# PHP/javascript - stream video using user's camera

Tags: php, camera

How I can stream video using visitor's camera? I would like to create something like Skype - stream the picture using camera from visitor's computer to another users which are visiting my page.

Here is my code:

```
<video id="video" width="640" height="480" autoplay></video>
<canvas id="canvas" width="640" height="480"></canvas>

<script type="text/javascript">
// Put event listeners into place
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
// Grab elements, create settings, etc.
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
    context = canvas.getContext("2d"),
    video = document.getElementById("video"),
    videoObj = { "video": true },
    errBack = function(error) {
        console.log("Video capture error: ", error.code); 
    };

// Put video listeners into place
if(navigator.getUserMedia) { // Standard
    navigator.getUserMedia(videoObj, function(stream) {
        video.src = stream;
        video.play();
    }, errBack);
} else if(navigator.webkitGetUserMedia) { // WebKit-prefixed
    navigator.webkitGetUserMedia(videoObj, function(stream){
        video.src = window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(stream);
        video.play();
    }, errBack);
}
else if(navigator.mozGetUserMedia) { // Firefox-prefixed
    navigator.mozGetUserMedia(videoObj, function(stream){
        video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
        video.play();
    }, errBack);
}
}, false);
</script>
```

But it works only for me (only I can see this picture).
How I can show this picture for everyone on my webpage?